# #define file type

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is

```
#define LBitmap std::list < CBITMAP *>
```

a good practice?

Edit:
Allright, what can I do to convince my boss that this is bad practice?

Comment: You could try smashing his face against the desk until he asks for mercy, this usually works. Also a LART can be used (any network card with sharp edges will do).

Comment: My my, Matteo. I'd prefer a subtler method, see my (edited) answer.

Comment: Why spend time convincing your boss?  That time is better spent looking for a new job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, its not a good practice to use #define in C++.

Its good to use typedef as this has a well defined scope

typedef is scope defined and compiler interprets its definition each time it meet which is not the in case of  #define. #define is interpreted as compile time itself.

Here is the MSDN definition of typedef and #define

A typedef declaration introduces a name that, within its scope, becomes a synonym for the type given by the type-declaration portion of the declaration

When using DEFINE statements, all instances of that statement are replaced by the value of the statement during a preprocessing phase.

```
#define LBitmap std::list < CBITMAP *>   // BAD

typedef std::list < CBITMAP *> LBitmap  // GOOD
```

**To convince your Boss**

```
#define CHARPTR char*
```

`CHARPTR a, b`;

After preprocessing, that line expands to

```
char* a, b;
```

Here, only variable a is of type char * whereas b is simply char

If you use typedef

```
typedef char* CHARPTR;
CHARPTR a, b;
```

Here both a and b are both of type char *

Comment: @Pradeep shouldnt typedef syntax be the otherway round :)        typedef std::list<CBITMAP *> LBitmap;

Comment: @Als Thanks Als, it was mistake when quoting example. Corrected this in solution

Answer (score 9):

No, the use of preprocessor macros (`#define`) is discouraged in C++. Use a `typedef` instead:

```
typedef std::list<CBITMAP *> LBitmap;
```

Edit: to convince your boss, you can use the pointer trick Pardeep posted, but it's even more <del>fun</del> instructive to introduce a subtle bug using references:

```
#define FooRef Foo &

struct Bar {
    Foo a, b;
};

void func(Bar &bar)
{
    FooRef a = bar.a, b = bar.b;
    a = some_value;
    b = another_value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

***#define*** is just an textual replace and it can lead a few problems, resulting in code that you dont intend to have.
   ***typedef*** if the right way to give alias names for datatypes etc.

Heres an example where #define fails horribly!

```
#define CHARPTR_DEFINE char*  
typedef char* CHARPTR_TYPEDEF;
CHARPTR_DEFINE ptr1, ptr2;   --> evaluates to char *ptr1, ptr2;
CHARPTR_TYPEDEF ptr3, ptr4;  -->evaluates to char *ptr3,*ptr4;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, for defining type aliases, there is a much better facility:

```
typedef std::list< CBITMAP *> LBitmap;
```

A `#define` results in a textual replacement, which can lead to surprising results. `typedef` on the other hand creates a proper alias for some other type.

Answer (score 1):

No. Its better to use a `typedef` in this case as:

```
typedef std::list<CBITMAP*> LBitmap;
```